# Rotate and compress HDFS Audit-Logs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, audit

i want to modify the Log4J configuration of the HDFS audit-log. The Log-Files have to be compress, if the filesize is greater than 100MB or at end of business. Files have to be rotate endloss.

I habe to tried to edit the log-configuration but the filesize will be ignore.

Best regards

Dominik

#### hdfs audit logging

```
 hdfs.audit.logger=INFO,console
 log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=${hdfs.audit.logger}
 log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=false
 log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/hdfs-audit.log
 log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%
 log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
 log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=2
 log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
 log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.MaxFileSize=100MB
 log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${hadoop.log.dir}/hdfs-audit.log
 log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${hadoop.log.dir}/hdfs-audit-%i.log.gz
```

Comment: Does the documentation for `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` say sizes are ignored?

Comment: No. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html